# how do i use data from one function in another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want to access couple of variables from one function inside another function and I don't know how can I do that.

code of the functions is given below

```py
def register():
    form1 = Signup()
    if form1.validate_on_submit():
        signin = auth_py.create_user_with_email_and_password(form1.email_address.data, form1.password.data)
        user = auth_py.send_email_verification(signin['idToken'])  # for email verification

        name = form1.name.data
        username = form1.username.data
        email_address = form1.email_address.data

        return redirect(url_for('home_page'))
    if form1.errors != {}:   # if no errors occur from validators
        for err_msg in form1.errors.values():
            print(f'there was an error creating the user {err_msg}')
    # database(username=username, name=name, email_address=email_address)
    return render_template('sign-up.html', form1=form1)


@app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form2 = Signin()
    if form2.validate_on_submit():
        user = auth_py.sign_in_with_email_and_password(form2.email.data, form2.password.data)
        user = auth_py.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
        data = auth_py.get_account_info(user['idToken'])   # get user information
        email_verified = data['users'][0]['emailVerified']
        print(email_verified)   # knowing weather user's email is verified or not
        return redirect(url_for('account_page'))

    if form2.errors != {}:   # if no errors occur from validators
        for err_msg in form2.errors.values():
            print(f'there was an error creating the user {err_msg}')
    return render_template('sign-in.html', form2=form2)
```

i want to use `name`, `username` and `email_address` from `register()` inside of `login()`, how can I do that?

Comment: You are querying user from `auth_py` in `login` function, but there is no code in `register` to keep the user data.

Comment: Traditionally, this is what the `session` dictionary is used for.  It carries state information for each browser's session.

Comment: @Vigen there is a commented function in `register`, named as `database`

Comment: @vanditvasa then check value of the `data` in `login` function, and be sure to call `database` in a right place (you need to store user data when `form1.validate_on_submit()` is true). It's hard to say what's wrong, because actual implementation of the `database` and `auth_py` is not posted.

Comment: Do you want user to be logged in with the details with which the user is trying to register? If so, you'll have to successfully register the user and then request the login api inside of the resgister api function. Please elaborate your usecase so that people can suggest you better.